# How to reuse contents in wpf/mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a UI that displays a pattern of "first name/last name".  So I thought I would reuse the same template. But I am facing some issues getting the binding right.

**Note:-**

*PrimaryContactDataContext* is nothing but a class, with a property named "value" which implements the *INotifyPropertyChanged" interface.

```
    <StackPanel>      
      <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=PrimaryContactDataContext.Value,Mode=TwoWay}"  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PersonalDetailsTemplate}"  />
    </StackPanel>

// See the Reusable template below 

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonalDetailsTemplate" >
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="30" Text="Name"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Width="110" Text="{Binding LastName}" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="30" Text="Title"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Width="110" Text="{Binding firstName}" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>               
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Last name and first name is not getting displayed.  even though the variable "PrimaryContactDataContext.value" has value in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `Content` of the `ContentControl`, not its `DataContext`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=PrimaryContactDataContext.Value,Mode=TwoWay}"  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PersonalDetailsTemplate}"  />
```